# R- Improving linear regression fit

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation

I am trying to construct a predictive model in R. I am using the glm() in R to fit the model. I am getting a very high residual error after fitting the model. My target values are in the range of 5*10^6 and I am getting an error of around 1 * 10^6. Can anyone please help me how can I improve my predictive model. Are there any parameters I can tweak so that my model will be better. Also, Can anyone suggest any other function I can use in R to fit my model? I am using the below code.

```
data<-read.csv("training.csv")
 sum(is.na(data))
 val_10_fold=NULL
 for(i in 1:10){
    model <- glm(Y ~ X1 + X2... X14 , data,family= gaussian())
    val_10_fold[i]<-cv.glm(data, model,K = 10)$delta[1]
  }
  summary(model)
  detach(data)

predicted_valid<-predict.glm(model, validation_data)
sum_valid=0
for( i in 1:1656){
  error_valid = (predicted_valid[i]- validation_data[i,3])^2;
  sum_valid=sum_valid+error_valid
}

sum_valid= sqrt(sum_valid/1656)

plot(predicted_valid, validation_data$Y, xlab = "Predictor variable", ylab = "Predicted variable"); 
points(predicted_valid, validation_data$Y, col = "blue")
```

[image]

This is the summary of my model.

```
 Call:
    glm(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + 
        X10 + X11 + X12 + X14, family = gaussian(), data = data_subset)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1599151    -52797     -7223     38855   2265792  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -8.95e+05   3.50e+06   -0.26  0.79836    
X1          -3.55e-03   2.15e-03   -1.65  0.09997 .  
X2          -2.62e+01   6.97e+01   -0.38  0.70697    
X3          -3.70e+01   1.76e+00  -21.02  < 2e-16 ***
..
..

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 1.82e+10)

    Null deviance: 2.3416e+14  on 3319  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 6.0258e+13  on 3306  degrees of freedom
AIC: 87877

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Comment: The constant variance assumption of the model you fitted is clearly false. Does this not concern you?

Comment: @Glen_b I am really sorry , I completely miss on that. Surely using a linear regression is  not going to help me. Do you think using a least square or weighted least square linear regression would be a better option?

Comment: ordinary least squares assumes constant variance, so that's no help. Weighted least squares might if you knew what weights to use. Personally, I'd probably lead toward using a different family in the GLM than the Gaussian, such as a gamma, or perhaps even taking a look at the possibility of working on the log-scale.

Comment: I tried modelling like Y ~ X1.. + logX4..+X14 as X4 variable didn't have constant variance. I also tried using loglm() in R but it is giving me some error. model <- loglm(Y ~ X1 + X2+...X14,data=data)
Error in table(fac) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements

Comment: @Glen_b I also tried using log log model and it reduced the residual error. But I am not sure how do I get the actual values of the target as i must be getting log(Y) values?

Comment: This is discusses in many posts here. What precise things to you need to get from the model?  Note that the GLM I suggested might suit you better as you don't have to back-transform anything.